# Mysql workbanch генерация модели из существующей БД

Tags: mysql

Кто работал с этой чудесной прогой, подскажите, можно ли геренировать модель исходя из существующей базы данных, чтобы подхватывались все связи между таблицами и их можно было наблюдать в модели? Или только создание модели с нуля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. На главной странице воркбенча (где выбираем соединение) есть поле под названием models. Справа от этого слова есть три значка. Надо кликнуть на третий (он похож на стрелку вправо), после этого из контекстного меню выбрать "Create EER Model from Database". Дальше я думаю любой разберется. Если что, еще нашел [видео](http://youtu.be/Wfy8rdhXyWw) с подробно описанным процессом.